# Bandwidth finder

Tags: bandwidth

Is there any programs or applications which will allow me to find out how much bandwidth I have used up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try [NetMeter](http://www.metal-machine.de/readerror/index.php?action=tpmod;dl=cat1). I used it in the past for [free](http://www.hootech.com/NetMeter/freedown.htm).  It can track the usage daily/weekly/monthly basis and can also issue an alert if the usage crosses a set threshold. It also can project the monthly usage based on current rate of use.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**[AnalogX NetStat Live](http://www.analogx.com/contents/download/network/nsl.htm)** is free.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[DU Meter](http://www.hageltech.com/dumeter/about)

DU Meter reports monthly / weekly / daily usage, can export reports in different formats, etc. Actually the software listed above is mainly copycats of DU Meter. Should at least try the original.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you store logs of bandwidth usage. On both linux and windows there are programs that will track this. A simple google search will result in answers to what programs.

Answer (score 0):

[**BitMeter II**](http://codebox.org.uk/controller?page=bitmeter2)

Includes historical data, on-screen stopwatch, download calculator, export data to a spreadsheet, monitoring your speed remotely over the internet via a web browser, ISP quota safeguard, and many other options.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Answer (score 0):

Many routers have the option to measure and save logs of your usage over periods of time. It may need to be enabled, but it is always accurate and doesn't cost anything. In addition, it shows usage by all devices and not just a single machine that a program would run on.